# Fluent NHibernate with a weird relationship

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate

### EmployeeTable

```
EmployeeId
EmployeeName
ManagerId
```

### ManagerClass

```
// EmployeeId of the manager
int ManagerId { get; set; }

// EmployeeName of the manager
string ManagerName { get; set; }

// EmployeeId of the employee that is attached to this manager
int ChildEmployeeId { get; set; }
```

A Manager is an Employee, also meaning that a ManagerId is an EmployeeId.  There is only one manager to one employee and one employee to one manager.

I have to figure out the NHibernate Fluent class map that can fill the Manager class above;  Any help on how this would look is greatly appreciated!!!

Please keep in mind this is a model/table that I've inherited with to much technical debt to make changes to it (from a time standpoint).

-Jessy Houle

Comment: Does Manager inherit from Employee in the class definition?

Comment: No.  Manager is the only class.  No, employee class.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a one-to-one circular mapping. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255950/fluent-nhibernate-how-to-create-circular-one-to-one-mapping

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is a [one-to-one](http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one) relationship.
(and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071274/fluent-nhibernate-one-to-one)'s how to do it in fluent)

Comment: It's a bit more then just a one-to-one that I'm looking for.  Notice, in the above example, it is self referencing as well.  However, I appreciate the quick turn around.